# Python3 & Opencv3 & Multiprocessing raise System Error

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, opencv3.0

I'm currently using OpenCV 3 with python 3.4. My machine is a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and I'm having problems when using some functions from OpenCV combined with the multiprocessing Library. Here is a (very) simplified sample code which reproduce the error:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy
import cv2


class Sample():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mask = []  # Testing

    def experiment(self):

        img = cv2.imread("/Users/luigolas/PycharmProjects/PyReid/tests/test_resources/P2/cam1/P2_001_cam1_1.png")
        self.mask.append(segment(img))
        print("Segmented!")
        processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=self._func) for i in range(3)]
        _ = [p.start() for p in processes]
        _ = [p.join() for p in processes]

    def _func(self):
        img = cv2.imread("/Users/luigolas/PycharmProjects/PyReid/tests/test_resources/P2/cam2/P2_001_cam2_1.png")
        cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        print("Done!!")


def segment(image):
    bgdmodel = numpy.zeros((1, 65), numpy.float64)
    fgdmodel = numpy.zeros((1, 65), numpy.float64)
    mask_source = "/Users/luigolas/PycharmProjects/PyReid/resources/masks/OptimalMask.txt"
    mask = numpy.loadtxt(mask_source, numpy.uint8)
    cv2.grabCut(image, mask, None, bgdmodel, fgdmodel, 2, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)

    mask = numpy.where((mask == 2) | (mask == 0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')

    return mask


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Sample()
    t.experiment()
```

The problem is that it never gets to the "Done!!" print, as it breaks showing an OS X error message. The full error message is in this [GIST](https://gist.github.com/Luigolas/c35f325020b634fbabdc)

I've been stuck with this for a while and haven't been able to find the exact reason of this error. If I don't run the "cvtcolor" command there is no problem at all. As well as if the "grabcut" command is not run...

**UDATE:**
In the _func method if I add a print or create a file as the first instruction it is printed and created, meaning that the process is launched.
The problem appears when both the grabcut (in segment function) and cvtcolor are executed. If one of those is not executed, there is no problem at all. How can it be related at all?

I also tried using `multiprocessing.dummy.Process` and it worked.
A problem with OpenCV maybe?

Comment: Try adding `with open('temp.txt', 'w') as fo: pass` to your `_func()` function. Run it again and look in your current working directory. If you see the file 'temp.txt' then you know that at least your subprocesses are launching correctly. If you don't see the file, then there is something wrong with the way you are trying to start the processes.

Comment: does it work if you use `multiprocessing.dummy.Process` (a thread instead of a process)? Does it crash if you make `_func(self)` a global function (I don't see `self` used anywhere), remove `segment()` call, e tc?

Comment: Yes skgrrgwasme. I tried that, and it creates the file.
J.F Sebastian, I tried the thread method and yes, it works that way. About being a class method, with self, it is that way because it is a simplified code to reproduce the error, but in my code I need to pass the self param. Anyway, if I make it just a function (not in the class, without self) it crash anyway.

If I remove segment call, it works. If I remove cv2.cvtColor call, it works. If both are present, the error is raised. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally solved it. It was a problem with the compilation & installation of OpenCV. Can't really tell what was wrong, but I checked how [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/opencv.rb) configure OpenCV and adapted it (adding python 3 support).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Having your same problem. It would have helped explaining the solution.

Comment: Right now I'm still with the problem when tested in other scenarios... I'll try to find a solution and post it here...